# Java cannot find symbol: constructor error

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, compiler-errors

I am writing a class (Suite) that is inheriting from another class (HotelRoom). The HotelRoom class has a constructor that requires an argument (an int) and so in the constructor for Suite I called super(room) which from what I can tell should work. HotelRoom complies just fine, however Suite gives the constructor error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code below:

```
public class HotelRoom
{
    private int roomNumber;
    protected double nightlyRate;
    private final int maxRoomNumber = 999;
    boolean didEnterCorrectRoomNumber = false;

    public HotelRoom(int room)
    {

        if (room > 0 && room <= 299)
        {
            nightlyRate = 69.95;
            didEnterCorrectRoomNumber = true;
            //return didEnterCorrectRoomNumber;
        }
        else if (room > 299 && room <= maxRoomNumber)
        {
            nightlyRate = 89.95;
            didEnterCorrectRoomNumber = true;
            //return didEnterCorrectRoomNumber;
        }
        else
        {
            //return didEnterCorrectRoomNumber;
        }
    }

    public int getRoomNumber ()
    {
        return roomNumber;
    }

    public double getNightlyRate ()
    {
        return nightlyRate;
    }
    public boolean getDidEnterCorrectRoomNumber ()
    {
        return didEnterCorrectRoomNumber;
    }

    public void displayRoom ()
    {
        System.out.println("Room Number: " + roomNumber);
        System.out.format("Cost per Night: $%.2f%n", nightlyRate);
    }

}
```

and my subclass:

```
public class Suite extends HotelRoom
{
    private final double suiteSurchargeRate = 40.00;
    private double nightlyRateWithSuite;

    public Suite (int room)
    {
        super(room);
        //boolean didEnterCorrectRoomNumber = super.getDidEnterCorrectRoomNumber();
        nightlyRateWithSuite = super.getNightlyRate() + suiteSurchargeRate;
        //return didEnterCorrectRoomNumber;
    }

    public void displayRoom ()
    {
        super.displayRoom();
        System.out.format("Suite Surcharge: $%.2f%n", suiteSurchargeRate);
        System.out.format("Total Cost per Night: $%.2f%n", nightlyRateWithSuite);
    }

}
```

Exact compiler error:

```
MacBook-Air:HotelRoom Nick$ javac Suite.java
Suite.java:12: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor HotelRoom(int)
location: class HotelRoom
    super(room);
    ^
1 error
```

I have saved and recompiled both a few times and I just get the same result. HotelRoom compiles fine, but Suite does not. They are the only two java files in their directory, so there are no issues with calling the wrong class. :)

Comment: could you post the error message text you're getting?

Comment: The code you've posted compiles fine. I suspect you had that error when you didn't have `super(room)`.

Comment: The code looks fine to me. Are you sure you didn't forget to recompile HotelRoom before compiling Suite? Or don't you have another HotelRoom class elsewhere? What's the exact error message from the compiler?

Comment: First time posting on here, so not sure if I should edit my first post or comment on it, so I'll do both.

Exact compiler error: MacBook-Air:HotelRoom Nick$ javac Suite.java Suite.java:12: cannot find symbol symbol : constructor HotelRoom(int) location: class HotelRoom super(room); ^ 1 error

I have saved and recompiled both a few times and I just get the same result. HotelRoom compiles fine, but Suite does not. They are the only two java files in their directory, so there are no issues with calling the wrong class. :)

Comment: Also, the code above is exactly how I have it when I have tried to compile and get the error. There has been nothing changed since. I am quite confused that someone has got it to compile as-is when it doesn't on mine. Is there perhaps a bug in my version of java?

Comment: There must be some old HotelRoom class in your classpath. Try deleting the .class files, and compiling both files at once: javac HotelRoom.java Suite.java

Answer (score 0):

I think it relates to your Java setup on your Mac. Using Java 1.6 on a PC running Linux it compiles and runs fine for me, tested with following Main class

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Suite suite = new Suite(10);
        suite.displayRoom();    
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Room Number: 0
Cost per Night: $69.95
Suite Surcharge: $40.00
Total Cost per Night: $109.95
```